# Puzzle Dragons Orb Encancing

Tags: ios, puzzle-and-dragons

The questions are simple:

When you have a couple natural (Awoken skill) enhanced orbs, and you activate a skill that enhances orbs including said enhanced orbs, do the effects of each 'enhance' add on to each other? Like, say, use Unicorn's skill on a board that already has enhanced light orbs from awoken skills.

Does the same thing happen when you activate two different enhance orb skills that can affect the same type of orb?

And if so, is the effect additive or multiplicative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Orb enhancement does *not* stack.**

An orb can be either normal or enhanced; there are no tiers of enhancement (double-enhanced, triple-enhanced, etc). If you use, for example, Athena's active skill which enhances all light and green orbs, but all light and green orbs were already enhanced, then the active skill has no effect.

You can test that this is true by examining the bonus you get for matching enhanced orbs: the multiplier from enhancement is shown in the middle of the match details (match number is on top and triggered leader multiplier is on the bottom). Try matching 3 enhanced orbs without doing anything special, then try matching 3 "double-enhanced" orbs of the same color; the enhancement multiplier should be the same in both cases. I can't tell you exactly what the multiplier will be since it depends on both the number of enhanced orbs in the match and on the number of orb enhance awakenings for that color your team has.

Comment: Aww...that sucks...